# Get (<<) Evaluate File Name

Tags: files-and-directories, save

This seems like a simple question due to lack of experience, but I can't seem to find an answer through searching. I am trying to read back a symbol from a `DumpSave`:

`DumpSave[NotebookDirectory[] <> "mySymbol.mx", mySymbol]`

Here, using NotebookDirectory[] got my file in the current directory like I wanted, but when I try to use either of the following with `Get`, it fails:

```
<< NotebookDirectory[] <> "DiscreteTreatmentRegion.mx";
<< Evaluate[NotebookDirectory[] <> "Mysymbol.mx"];
```

It seems to me like it is not evaluating the filename correctly, since since it gives the message 'Cannot open ("NotebookDirectory[]").'

How can I get this to work? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: This `<< (NotebookDirectory[] <> "defs.mx")` works for me in a similar situation. Try closing MMA, then loading the notebook in question and running your second line again. Obviously the notebook needs to be saved.

Comment: `StringJoin` (`<>`) binds more loosely than `Get` (`<<`), it appears. the first example is interpreted as `Get[NotebookDirectory[]] <> "file.mx"`, but the second line with `Evaluate` should work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<<` is one of a few special operators which turn everything that follows into a string, without having to use quotes.

Thus `<< asd` is just another notation for `Get["asd"]`.  Note that the first form has no quotation marks.  Illustration:

[image]

The answer to your problem is: use the `Get` form, and not `<<`, if the file name is computed as an expression.  `<<` is a convenient shorthand for when you type the file name directly.

Some other stringifying operators are `>>`, `>>>`, `::`, and since version 10, `#`.  `#asd` is the same as `Slot["asd"]`.

This is documented under the "File Names" section [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html#26140).

Comment: I was trying to find good reference in docs for that. Are you aware of any? ps. NotebookDirectory[] was eveluate in my case but failed to get the data anyway.

Comment: @Kuba There's a mention under Details for `Get`: *<<"name" is equivalent to <<name. The double quotes can be omitted if the name is of the form specified in "Operator Input Forms".*

Comment: I saw that but I wouldn't say it is informative.

Comment: I see now, hmm I complain to much on docs so let me just go to say nothing more.

Comment: @Kuba I agree. I added a reference which is a bit better.  It mentions which characters can terminate the string (file name).  I don't know if `#` is different, it probably is.

Comment: @Kuba There's the Give Feedback link at the bottom of the online doc pages. In my experience they usually act on reasonable improvement request, though a bit slowly.

Comment: Nothing I've reported about improving documentation was fixed and lately I'm not getting any confirmation e-mail about a request beeing received (all info about license etc. included) so I decided to no care so much. There is couple of GB docs after all... For latest releases it wasn't even evaluated+saved to include/check consistency.

Comment: Oh, I was supposed to stop whining...